# Getting ALSA cannot find card '0' whilst trying to play audio files on my VPS Debian server

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa, vps, sox

I am trying to play audio on a Debian server with sox.

But I get these errors:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Floating point exception
```

Details about my systems:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I installed: alsa-oss and alsa-utils.

The audio file trying to play is an mp3.

I am using the `root` user.

To give more context, I am trying to play audio via Pulseaudio network on a VPS server.

I was reading that it could be that the Kernel of this VPS Debian might not have the audio support. Is there a way to verify this? And is there a way around this issue so that I can play audio files on my VPS and play it via Pulseaudio Newtork?

Comment: These error messages show that sox is trying to use an ALSA kernel driver, not PulseAudio. How did you configure PulseAudio and ALSA?

Comment: I did not configure anything. I just installed with `apt-get` pulseaudio. So you could say I have the default configurations.

Comment: See https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/ and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples.